# How long is the initial adjusting phase for a senior IT role?

Tags: new-job

Soon I'll be starting a new job as a senior IT data developer.

What is the expected warm-up time until I'm supposed to be fully operative?

During one of the interviews, the answer I got was "as soon as possible" but I didn't insist on getting a more precise answer. 
I proficiently use around 70% of the tools that I'll be using at my new job but I don't have a clue about the remaining 30%, industry specific business processes, quantity/quality of databases, data warehouses nor other details.

p.s. 
It's a small enterprise (less than 30 employees)

Comment: If the company didn't give you a firm answer when you asked them, they don't have a concrete expectation in mind. For a small company and a senior role, I would expect 1-2 month ramp up depending on how many other people of your position work at or have worked for the company...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to be expected to know all of the tools instantly, but you should be able to pick them up quite quick, and become self sufficient within your probationary period (if there is one).

The main thing for a senior developer is knowledge of techniques (problem solving) and processes (like releases). So long as you have these down, you can figure out the frameworks using tools like StackOverflow.